# "Rotating" a ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

I have an ArrayList in the board game-like game I am developing in Java, I format this ArrayList as a square, as so (numbers being indexs);

```
/*
 *  |0 |1 |2 |3 |
 *  |4 |5 |6 |7 |
 *  |8 |9 |10|11|
 *  |12|13|14|15|
 */
```

What I want to do is take this ArrayList and rotate it;

e.g turn() would output (based on the original index)

```
/*
 *  |0 |4 |8 |12|
 *  |1 |5 |9 |13|
 *  |2 |6 |10|14|
 *  |3 |7 |11|15|
 */
```

My current approach is breaking the ArrayList in to rows with a getRow() function i wrote and manually writing the rows back

Comment: Do you have ArrayList of ArrayList?

Comment: Just a note, the values can be "null"

Comment: This is called transposition

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941997/how-to-transpose-listlist

Comment: so you have 16 values in an ArrayList?

Comment: I would a) use a 2D array and b) flip the index values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
        for(int j = i; j < 4; ++j){
            int t1 = al.get(i).get(j);
            al.get(i).set(j, al.get(j).get(i));
            al.get(j).set(i, t1);
        }
    }
```

it's called matrix transpose.