# Java - transposing a list of list using streams

Tags: java, list, stream

For improvement purposes, I am trying to use exclusively streams to transpose a list of list.

By that I mean, that I have a List of List of Doubles that contains for example

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

And I would like to obtain a List of List of Doubles that contains

```
1 5
2 6
3 7
4 8
```

An iterative way is provided in the following Stack Overflow question : [How to transpose List<List>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941997/how-to-transpose-listlist/2942026)

I have only thought of ugly solutions so far, such as replacing the Double with a custom object that holds the value and the index in the list, flatten using flatMap, build it again using groupBy with the index I saved and then go back to Doubles.

Please let me know if you are aware of any clean way. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like your question!  Here's a simple way to achieve it, as long as the `List`s are square (every `List` contains the same number of elements):

```
List<List<Integer>> list = List.of(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4), List.of(5, 6, 7, 8));

IntStream.range(0, list.get(0).size())
         .mapToObj(i -> list.stream().map(l -> l.get(i)).collect(Collectors.toList()))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The above code returns the following:

```
[[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8]]
```

**Note**: This will not perform well for large lists.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell me why is the performance bad for long lists ? I take it there the complexity order heightens - is it caused by the .stream() being O(depth 2 list length) and thus inducing a O(depth 2 list length²) term ? If I'm using ArrayList s, the .map(l -> l.get(i)) call should be O(depth 2 list length), right ?

Comment: Well this method creates a `Stream` for each element of one of the `List`s in `list`. It's equivalent to a nested for-loop and its time complexity is `O(n * m)`. There exist many algorithms to transpose matrices that will perform better than this, especially with the added stream overhead.