# Combining 2 lists with streams in Groovy

Tags: groovy, functional-programming

Say I have two lists of equal size [1, 2, 3, 4, ...] and [a, b, c, d, ...]. Is there a way I make a map with streams that maps 1 to a, 2 to b, 3 to c, and so on without using lambda functions or nested functions?

I would use map and pass in a function, but this passed-in function can only take 1 argument and I need both pieces of information to map the elements to each other.

```
IntStream(1, list1.size()).stream().map(this.&combineListsFunction).collect...
```

`combineListsFunction` can only use the information from the stream, but I need both lists for the function to work.

Comment: There is a zip method in Guava, StreamEx, and probably other libraries for joining two streams in Java

Answer (score 1):

You can transpose both lists (which will give you a list of tuples and then create the map from it with `collectEntries()` (which takes exactly this).  E.g.:

```
def l1 = [1,2,3]
def l2 = ["a","b","c"]

assert [(1): "a", (2): "b", (3): "c"] == [l1,l2].transpose().collectEntries()
```

Comment: Is there a more general way to solve the problem of using `map` but the function passed in needs multiple pieces of information? I simplified my actual question, but did not anticipate that the simplified question would have its own specific answer.

Comment: AFAIK no.  `map` takes a `Function` and so you have to provide a function with one argument, that would take e.g. a list and destructure yourself.  Or you capture something from the outside (provide a closure to map.  E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49388245/java-transposing-a-list-of-list-using-streams). Or go hunt for the missing `zip` function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip