# Java switch columns to rows

Tags: java

Now I wanna to trans columns to Rows such as following example:
There're some List:

```
List1: {"1","2","3"}
List2: {"1","2","3","4"}
List3: {"1","2","3","4","5"}
```

Then I wanna trans them to :

```
ListA: {"1","1","1"}
ListB: {"2","2","2"}
ListC: {"3","3","3"}
ListD: {"","4","4"}
ListE: {"","","5"}
```

The following is my solution:

```
List<List<String>> list = Lists.newArrayList(
                Lists.newArrayList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
                Lists.newArrayList("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                Lists.newArrayList("1", "2", "3"));
List<List<String>> res = Lists.newArrayList();
TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(List::size, Function.identity(), (b1, b2) -> b1, TreeMap::new));
int size = map.get(map.lastKey()).size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    int finalI = i;
    res.add(list.stream().map(list1 -> {
        if (list1.size() > finalI) {
            return list1.get(finalI);
        }
        return "";
    }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

But it's complexity is O(n²), is there any other better solution?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941997/how-to-transpose-listlist

Comment: Well, that's complexity is also O(n²)，maybe there is not any better solusion?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create input list
    List<String> list1 = List.of("1", "2", "3");
    List<String> list2 = List.of("1", "2", "3", "4");
    List<String> list3 = List.of("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");

    // Create ouput list
    List<List<String>> outputList = new ArrayList<>();

    // Iterate for max length of lists
    IntStream
        .range(0, getMax(list1, list2, list3))
        .forEach(index -> {
            outputList.add(
                Arrays.asList(getElementByIndexOrEmpty(list1, index),
                    getElementByIndexOrEmpty(list2, index),
                    getElementByIndexOrEmpty(list3, index))
            );
        });

    System.out.println(outputList);
}

// Return element at index if present else return empty string
private static String getElementByIndexOrEmpty(List<String> list, int index) {
    return list.size() > index ? list.get(index) : "";
}

// Find max length of lists
private static int getMax(List<String> list1, List<String> list2, List<String> list3) {
    return Math.max(list1.size(), Math.max(list2.size(), list3.size()));
}
```

The code iterates through all the list only once (for the max length of any list).

Comment: Well, that's fine for this example.In fact, the datasource(i.g. list1, list2, list3 in this case) maybe three or more, so your solution may not suitable for much more common case. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: You can implement getMax function to accept variable arguments of int type and then return the max of it.